# Vue 3 with TypeScript cannot read properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have some problems with Vue 3 and TypeScript. I had one property 'user' that was a string, and I returned object from backend, so ofc it broke, I changed the property type to object but I'm still receiving error like:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'email')

This is how I'm calling it in front.

```
{{ item.user.email }}
```

It's actually in v-for, real property is items (array ofc)

So in props it was String, and I changed it to object, like so:

```
 props: {
    user: {
      type: Object,
      default: undefined
    },
```

And I have transformer like:

```
const  gTransformer = (data: GResponse[]): CARD[]  => {
      console.info(data)
      return data.map((element, index): CARD => ({
          id: element.id,
          status: element.status,
          created_at: moment(element.created_at).toDate(),
          updated_at: moment(element.updated_at).toDate(),
          user: element.user
        })
      )

}
```

And this is how GResponse interface looks like:

```
export interface GResponse {
  id: number;
  status: number;
  user: any;
  created_at: string,
  updated_at: string
}
```

and CARD interface is like:

```
export interface GiftCard {
  id: number;
  status: SomeEnum,
  user: any;
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. It's unknown what happens on back end, and the code doesn't contain enough information on what happens on front end . This is runtime error, so TS types are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Define your prop types for TypeScript in Vue3 Options API like this: [source](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props)

```js
import { PropType } from 'vue'
...
props: {
  user: undefined as PropType<Object | undefined>
},
```